# Which of this two Java snippets is faster as converting a string to a long?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I want to convert a string to a long. Which is more performant?

```
new Long(String)
```

or

```
Long.parseLong(String)
```

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to point out that *this is most likely irrelevant* to your application's performance which one you use.

Don't waste your time micro-optimizing ... unless you've profiled your code and the profiling tells you that these particular calls make a significant contribution to overall performance.  And once you've done that, it will be a *trivial* task to try the alternative method and rerun the profiling to see if it made a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `java.lang.Long` [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Long.java.html), the `Long(String)` constructor is calling `Long.parseLong(String, int)` internally. As Chandra Sekhar pointed out though, calling `Long.parseLong(String)` directly will give you back a primitive `long` value, which will generally perform faster than the boxed `Long` type.

Answer (score 0):

First case will give you a full fledged **Long** Wrapper class object. But the second one will give you a **long** primitive typed value.

So as per my view it is better  to use primitive type instead of object unless the situation forces to use the object.